# Where can I obtain an SQLite 3 command line binary for Android?

Tags: shell, terminal, sqlite

When I read documentation such as [examining SQLite 3 databases from a remote shell](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite) I get the impression an SQLite command-line binary should exist on my phone. Sadly I can't seem to find it on my phone (but I'm running a custom ROM).

I've read a few other posts that either allude to the existence of such a binary or mention how it is only available in the emulator, but there is nothing definitive.

Is such a binary available anywhere?

Other references:

- [Re: SQLite3](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg06553.html)
- *[Using SQLite from Shell in Android](http://www.infinitezest.com/articles/using-sqlite-from-shell-in-android.aspx)*
- *[Why does the SQLite 3 command using the Android ADB shell return “permission denied”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645122/)*
- *[Android – How to poke around the sqlite3 databases](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/11/android-how-to-poke-around-the-sqlite3-databases/)*

Comment: I suppose you could try pulling it from another ROM (or the emulator) and putting it on your device, but I have no idea if that would work or just crash. CM6, for instance, has the `sqlite3` binary.

Comment: on my Samsung Spica -- using Samdroid mod -- I can just type sqlite3 in terminal emulator or adb shell.

Comment: Is this a dev question?

Comment: @Matthew - nope

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet would be to use ADB and pull it off the emulator, or pull it from another ROM. You will then have to put it on your device, but you will have to have root to put it in the directory with the other binaries.

`sqlite3` does not come on most of the devices. I think it only comes on the developer phones, like ADP1/ADP2, and Nexus One/Nexus S. I know it is not on the Samsung Galaxy S devices such as the Vibrant (I am guessing it's on the Nexus S).

Answer (score 4):

As other posts have mentioned, the `sqlite3` binary is typically used via ADB from your PC.

If all you want to do is manage SQLite DBs locally, then I've found the free app [aSQLiteManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.andsen.asqlitemanager) very useful. In addition to a simple GUI for managing and viewing data, it allows running of arbitrary queries.

Answer (score 3):

I have put together some build scripts to compile SQLite for Android Native Code using the Android NDK. It builds the SQLite CLI in two versions: Statically and Dynamically Linked, as well as it's Static and Shared Libraries. You may get the scripts from my GitHub and build the binaries yourself:

https://github.com/stockrt/sqlite3-android

Hope this will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 2):

[SuperOneClick](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682) actually has a copy of the binary. It lives in the `Dependencies` folder, and [according to one poster on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5022363/390989), it works when pushed onto your device (I assume it *must* work on most devices since SuperOneClick uses it).

Answer (score 0):

Pulling it off of the emulator won't work.

I found a 1.6 binary [here](http://www.zois.co.uk/tn/tn-2010-09-16.html#dl).  That page details information on porting, so if the 1.6 binary doesn't work, you can try porting/compiling a new version.

Answer (score 0):

[tech128 from XDA Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2730422) provides compiled `sqlite3` binary for Android.

As of current writing,

> Here's SQLite 3.8.11.1 combined into a single source file (the amalgamation) for ARM v6 and v7.
>
> These binaries are built with optimized armv6 and armv7 flags.
>
> Should work on Android 2.x and up.
>
> I have attached 2 versions to this thread, compressed and uncompressed.
>   I had to change the extension to `.xap` otherwise I can't upload it.
>   **Just remove the extension**.
>
> Just download and run the uncompressed file, whereas compressed you have to decompress it first.
>
> Compressed
>
> - armv6: http://d-h.st/58Nn
> - armv6-nofpu: http://d-h.st/2ruo
> - armv7: http://d-h.st/UyJD
> - armv7-pie: http://d-h.st/xY2U
>
> Uncompressed
>
> - armv6: http://d-h.st/P5Im
> - armv6-nofpu: http://d-h.st/z0Ca
> - armv7: http://d-h.st/iiuF
> - armv7-pie: http://d-h.st/0Kp9
>
> Source code: https://github.com/tech128/sqlite3

I have tested the armv7-pie (PIE needed for Lollipop) on my Nexus 5 running Android 5.1.1 Lollipop, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found a binary that worked on github https://github.com/tech128/sqlite3
relevant xda-developers thread https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2730422

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) and install `sqlite3` via the built-in `apt` (front end of the built-in `dpkg`).

Answer (score -1):

A little complicated process I will suggest, because I am not aware of other ways :) , 
get the Android source code , compile it , in the output directory you will get sqlite3 binary , then push it to your phone's /system/bin/