# SQLite database operation from Android terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, sqlite

I want to do SQLite command like `sqlite3 myDb.db`, or do other SQLite command from Android shell, like Terminal Emulator or something else.

I have tried googling for these, but no luck. Is it possible to do that? If it is, how to do it?

I'm using locally-made Android phone in my country, based on Jelly Bean OS.

Comment: Closely related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5053/where-can-i-obtain-an-sqlite3-command-line-binary-for-android-2-2-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if you have `sqlite3` binary for Android installed. Most of Android devices don't have this binary. If your device doesn't have it, then you need to get the proper binary and install it (refer to [Where can I obtain an SQLite 3 command line binary for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5053/44325)). Note that you **need root access** to do this.

After getting the `sqlite3` binary, place it inside `system/bin/` (or `system/xbin/`). After this, you just need to test if the terminal can access  the binary by calling `sqlite3` from there. If it shows `sqlite>` prompt and SQLite version, then you're done.

For usage hints, on `sqlite3`, write `.help`.

```
sqlite> .help
```

Comment: +1 There is also [SQLite Installer for root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ptSoft.util.sqlite3forroot&hl=en) that would install the binary for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Termux for installing `sqlite`.

Type

```
$ pkg I sqlite
```

and there you go on Android.